# How do I send utf-8 data using pika?

Tags: python, unicode, amqp, pika

I am trying to post a unicode string over pika. When I send it I get this message:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 6-20: ordinal not in range(128)
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/simplebuffer.py", line 62, in write
    self.buf.write(data)
```

Looking around, it seems I have to set the charset or content type to UTF-8 using pika.BasicProperties, but i can't find documentation on that class.

What should I set to post unicode data?

Comment: Have you tried encoding first?

Comment: calling 'γαλακτομπούρεκο'.encode('utf-8') worked! thank you

(if you're curious, thats a Greek dessert. I like using food as test data :) )

Answer (score 0):

```
 properties = BasicProperties(
        app_id=self.app_id,
        content_type='application/json',
        content_encoding='utf-8',
        delivery_mode=2,
    )
channel.basic_publish(exchange=exchange,
                          routing_key=routing_key,
                          body=message_body,
                          properties=properties)
```